# c# should i use string with regex matchs or not

Tags: c#, regex, string-matching

I have a text that I am going to find matchs within that text and after that putting the results on array .

when I tried to make string array and string variables I found that it's really confusing to change from MatchCollection type to String type . and I get the error cannot convert .

what type of array and variables should I use ?
and what is the need for string type . I was just using it since I deal with string.

I want to notice that I am going to compare between arrays to find common matchs

here is my full code so far 
[c# regex array or list and which type string or what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35810006/c-sharp-regex-array-or-list-and-which-type-string-or-what)

Comment: Could you please post the code that cause problem?

Comment: I'd use a generic list `List<String> mylist =new  List<String>();` to keep the matches in a list. The type of the text matches should be declared as String : `String match;`. You can add your matches to the list like `mylist.Add(match);`

Comment: aha so i can declar String match , instead of MatchCollection .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
string sample = "1a2b3c4d";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(sample, @"\d");

List<string> matchesList = new List<string>();

foreach (Match match in matches) 
    matchesList.Add(match.Value);

matchesList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

or use LINQ:

```
List<string> matchesList2 = new List<string>();

matchesList2.AddRange(
    from Match match in matches
    select match.Value
);

matchesList2.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: what is the different between .foreach and .Addrange

Comment: in foreach you add values one by one, AddRange adds values from IEnumerable that created by linq request

Comment: linq request ? what is that .

Comment: and which one should i use with objects . 
i will creat the array on a class .

Comment: feel free to discover **msdn** [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) , foreach will _probably_ work faster

Comment: sure sure . you have made my day . :) 
i am going to be busy for the next a few hours :) 
your code is less on space and more simple than mine . 
thank you very much . 
you have got a correct answer but my points still less than 15 >