# c# regex array or list and which type string or what?

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, string, match

I am sorry for this long question, but it's provided to help this topic and my other topics. so please dont give me negative feed. I am still beginner here.

I have a text, I have splited it then found match's with in the splits and I printed the matchs form each split to test my code, but I am stuck with the following step.

but before i do i want to point out that i am searching for 6 types of matchs and each match will be repeated.the final view is : each split data will be extract to an object from class with 6 variables. each one variable contain the matchs of its own type. next step but later i am going to compare between the same variable in different objects
so each split = new object

so I made a function to search inside the splits.calling it 6 times with different delimiter but same split.

QUESTION:

Can I do this in 1 step ?
My problem is that I want to put the match's of each type into an array.

1. should i use Array or list ?
2. what type should i use for that array ? string or matchs or something else.
   what is the benefit of using string.
3. what is point of using the string, if the writeline print string from match :) ?

Here is my function which as you can see doesn't return array ( it will be great if i can do that.

```
public static MatchCollection theLineAfterMatch( string inputString, string DELIMITER )
{
    MatchCollection allLinesAfterMatches = null;
    var regexObj = new Regex(@"(?<=" + DELIMITER + ").*");
    allLinesAfterMatches = regexObj.Matches(inputString);
    return allLinesAfterMatches;
}
```

Here is how I call it

```
MatchCollection firstmatch= theLineAfterMatch(textfromsplit, firstMatchDelimiter);
MatchCollection secoundmatch= theLineAfterMatch(textfromsplit, secoundMatchDelimiter);
```

and i do that 6 times :(

Here is the writeline test

this step is repeated 6 times

```
foreach (Match m in firstmatch)
{
    Console.WriteLine("LinkStateRouterID : " + m.Value);
}
```

Or this I dont know the different

```
for (int i = 0; i < firstmatch.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("firstmatch: " +firstmatch[i].ToString());
}
```

Now how to add the matchs of each type to arrays. With consideration that a comparison will happened between the arrays of the same type.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Can you post same text data and delimiters?

Comment: almost the same text as here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19193251/regex-to-get-the-words-after-matching-string

Comment: Ok. Can you show the delimiters you use and sample results you expect to get?

Comment: Please narrow down your post and ask just one specific question pertinent to the problematic part of your code. Thanks and regards,

Comment: oki i am going to delete this and ask with a better Question way .